# How to do conditional upsert in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

My go code for upserting a list of records using gorm upsert:

```golang
if err := appdb.GetDBCli().Clauses(gormclause.OnConflict{
        Columns:   []gormclause.Column{{Name: "user_uuid"}, {Name: "node_id"}, {Name: "class_uuid"}},
        DoUpdates: gormclause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"current", "status", "content", "description", "remark", "attributes"}),
    }).Create(records).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, apperr.DbQueryError
    }
```

How do I make it possible for gorm to NOT update the description column, and just ignore the value, **if** there is a conflict
**and** the record.description being saved is an empty string?

Comment: your last sentence is too complex, can you edit it a little?

Comment: @Christian People often use wrong tag `gorm` for gorm.io(https://gorm.io/). The correct tag will be `go-gorm`(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gorm). I hope correct tag helps the future reader.